# Second order differential equations where the r.h.s. ${}= 6e^2\cos(3x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differrential equation  $$y'' - 4y' + 13y' = 6e^{2x}\cos(3x)$$  where $y(0)=3$ and $y'(0)=-8$.

I think we start like…

For the homogenous case
$$\lambda^2 -4\lambda + 13 = 0 $$
\begin{align}
\lambda &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
&= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{16-52}}{2} \\
&= \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{-36}}{2} \\
&= \frac{4 \pm 6i}{2} \\
&= 2 \pm 3i
\end{align}
$$\lambda_1 = 2+3i \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda_2 = 2-3i$$

The homogenous equation has a general solution

$$y_{\text{h}} = Ae^{(2+3i)x}\cos(3x) +Be^{(2-3i)x}\sin(3x)$$

Since the R.H.S. is an non-homogenous equation “$6e^{2x}\cos(3x)$” we choose the trial function $$y_{\text{p}} = (\alpha e^{(2+3i)x} \cos(3x)+\beta e^{(2-3i)x}\sin(3x))$$

I’m not sure how to procede from here or whether I am going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be $$y''-4y'+13y=6e^{2x}\cos(3x).$$
The solution of the homogenous part is given by
$$y(x)= c_1e^{2 x}\sin (3 x)+c_2 e^{2 x} \cos (3 x).$$
For the inhomogenous solution, set
$$y_{\text{P}}=e^{2x}(Ax\sin(3x)+B\cos(3x)).$$

Comment: Do you mean $y_h = y(x) = c_1 e^{2x} sin(3x) + c_2e^{2x} cos{3x}$

Comment: yes sorry some $c_1$ is missing

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your homogeneous solution can either be $$y_h = Ae^{2x+3ix}+Be^{2x-3ix}$$ or $$y_h = Ce^{2x}\cos(3x)+De^{2x}\sin(3x)$$

They are equivalent.

Also, why would you try the function $\cos \ \& \ \sin 4x$? Trial function should be $$y_p=x\,e^{2x}\, \cos (3x)+x\,e^{2x}\, \sin (3x)$$

For this method to work, if you take derivatives of the inhomogeneous part, you must get a finite number of different functions. When some of the derivatives of the inhomogeneous part happen to be identical to the homogeneous solution, you need to multiply your trial function by $x$. I suggest you to read more about this method.

Comment: Wait i'm confused about the homogenous solution, why do you have to solutions for the homogenous solution? I get $y_h = Ce^{2x} cos(3x) + D e^{2x} sin (3x)$ but i don't get why $y_h = Ae^{(2+3o)x} + Be^{(2-3i)x}$ is also there. Do i need to consider both of them?

Comment: @Ivan Those two solutions are *identical* https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/0/2/102c800960cd830aa1a0f0ae7c7e779e.png Linear combination (the constants $ABCD$) of {sinx, cosx} are equivalent to $e^{+ix},e^{-ix}$

Comment: What i don't get is how come for the second one the complex roots do not affect the homogenous equation. So i didn't have to solve for the roots at all?

Comment: Do you accept the first one to be *a* correct answer?

Comment: If so, lets take $A=1$ and $B=1$. We have $$2e^{2x}\frac{e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}}{2}=2e^{2x}\cos (3x)$$ as per this formula:https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/1/0/2/102c800960cd830aa1a0f0ae7c7e779e.png So (A=1,B=1) is equivalent to (C=2,D=0). I can do this for ANY A and B.

Comment: Hey so isn't $y_p = C_1 xe^{2x} cos(3x) + C_2 xe^{2x} sin(3x)$ would i be right to differentiate this twice and sub in the given conditions?

Comment: yes, that is what you should do. You should get $C_2=1$

Comment: But the initial condition says y(0) = 3 but if sub in x=0 for y_p the whole thing equals 0

Comment: homogeneous solution does not equal zero. you must consider the sum of homogeneous and particular

Comment: Hey so i did i subbed in $y_p'', y_p', y_p $ and it worked out beautifully everything cancelled out so that.... $\beta cos(3x)-\alpha sin(3x) = cos(3x)$ i'm not sure what to do with this. Was i looking for the value of x? X got cancelled out.

Comment: Oh at x = 0, $\alpha$ = 1 and at x=1 $\alpha$ = 0